# PHP dont receive data from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, response

i have a problem with ajax and PHP. When i try to send data from ajax to PHP, ajax seems work, because a alert show data correctly (although during a short time, next dissapear), but in my php file dont show any data (i inspect with developers tools and nothing result)
this is my ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla_eventos').on('click', '#guardar_bt', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var filaactual = $(this).closest("tr"); 
        var id_evento = filaactual.find("td:eq(0)").html(); 
        var parametros = {
            id_evento : id_evento
        };
        $.ajax({
            method:  'POST', 
            data:  parametros, 
            url:   'detalle_evento.php', 
            success:  function (response) {
                        location.href='detalle_evento.php';
                        alert('bien'+' '+id_evento);
                      }
        });
    });
});
```

and this is my php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
    <?php
    echo $_POST['id_evento'];
    ?>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What result are you expecting? What do you see in your browser console when you add `console.log(response);` to your `success` callback?

Comment: Does $POST have anything in it?

Comment: $_POST dont show nothing

Comment: console.log(response) dissapear quickly. alert(response) show response correctly

Comment: With `location.href='detalle_evento.php';` you are immediately redirecting the browser to another page as soon as the Ajax finishes, so that's why you don't see anything, or why the console output disappears quickly. the whole point of Ajax is to allow the browser to stay on the same page while talking to the server, so why do you then want to change the page immediately after the Ajax has completed? Maybe you need to think again about this design. You already make an Ajax request to that same URL, so why do you need to redirect to it? Maybe you misunderstood how to use AJAX properly

Comment: Your javascript is sending `id_evento` via POST, then upon receiving the reply (which is the html output of detalle_evento.php) it immediately is redirecting to another page (which is the same php script but without the POST parameter).  So what shows up is the page with no POST value.

Comment: I understand, if i use only js this must work, or not? Thanks ADyson and all response

Comment: `i use only js this must work`...yes it can work with JS. Change your success function to `success:  function (response) { alert('bien ' + response); }` and see what result you get. You should get back all the HTML from your detalle_evento.php PHP file, with the ID in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line in your code:

```
location.href='detalle_evento.php';
```

Just after script receive data from ajax the page is reloading with empty data in POST (because the reload is a GET request).

If you want to use this data in this way then add this code to your HTML (in body section).

```
<form action="detalle_evento.php" method="post" id="someform">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_evento" id="id_evento" value="<?= $_POST['id_evento'] ?>">
</form>
```

and use this JS code

```
document.getElementById("id_evento").value = id_evento;
document.getElementById("someform").submit();
```

instead of this part of your code

```
$.ajax({
        method:  'POST', 
        data:  parametros, 
        url:   'detalle_evento.php', 
        success:  function (response) {
                    location.href='detalle_evento.php';
                    alert('bien'+' '+id_evento);
                  }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but, i try with method GET and i have the same result.

Comment: @DiegoK. - I think that you don't understand what you are doing. When you post data in ajax the response is correct (try it - look what value returns in response value in your JS). When you reload page there is noting in GET and POST data - the reload is a new and  fresh request with no data. If you want to reload page with POST then use a form instead of ajax (and submit it with JS instead of executing ajax). Ajax is ok when you want to do something with data or just get new data to display it (then in success section you need to use response to change something in your view).